# Using iptables to re-write the source address of certain incoming packets?

Tags: iptables

I have an application where a device is sending UDP traffic to a Linux box where it gets replicated using UDP samplicator and sent to multiple other devices for analysis. The UDP samplicator is configured to preserve the source addresses of the original incoming packets when they get replicated. That part works perfectly.

I use iptables on the samplicator box today to selectively not forward UDP traffic from certain sources to specific analysis targets because some of the analysis targets only need to see data from certain devices, and that also works perfectly.

Where I'm running into trouble is that there are a few devices that I need to re-write the source addresses on their incoming UDP traffic to overcome some limitations with one specific device vendor.  The easiest way to overcome this limitation that I can see would be to use iptables on the samplicator to re-write the source address on incoming UDP packets from device 10.1.2.3 before those packets get replicated to the analysis targets so they see the traffic coming another address, such as 10.4.5.6.

Since this is UDP and the analysis targets are not directly responding to the UDP packets they receive from the devices, I don't need to worry about translating traffic bi-directionally.

- 10.1.2.3 = IP address that the device's UDP traffic is coming from
- 10.4.5.6 = The IP address that we need to see it coming from
- 10.7.8.9 = one of the analysis targets

I tried this on my samplicator box:
`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p udp -s 10.1.2.3 --dport 6343 -j SNAT --to-source 10.4.5.6:6343`

however on the analysis targets, I still see lots of UDP traffic coming through with source address 10.1.2.3, and nothing with 10.4.5.6.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 host 10.1.2.3 and port 6343
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol  decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:02:56.443038 IP 10.1.2.3.19147 > 10.7.8.9.6343: sFlowv5, IPv4 agent 10.1.2.3, agent-id 2, length 276
19:02:56.914536 IP 10.1.2.3.55326 > 10.7.8.9.6343: sFlowv5, IPv4 agent 10.1.2.3, agent-id 1, length 1336
```

I tried a few other options in iptables, but none seemed to work.  Any insight anyone could offer regarding how to get the NAT working correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

POSTROUTING means: happens *after* *routing*. Two conditions that are not met (nor wanted): you receive traffic with tcpdump *before* (so you'll never capture this change with this tool) and there is no *routing* at all involved since the samplicator *local process* is the destination. If you routed them (in PREROUTING, allowing only DNAT, not SNAT), samplificator would be bypassed, not what you'd want either.

Don't despair, NAT is not used only with routing. You can still NAT the source destined to a *local process*. tcpdump will still happen *before* (because it's using RAW sockets) so will see the original source ip and not help with debugging, but your application, as long as it's not using SOCK_RAW to receive traffic, will see the altered source. I checked samplificator's source, it looked like it is receiving packets like usual applications (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM).

so the right command should use INPUT, not POSTROUTING:

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p udp -s 10.1.2.3 --dport 6343 -j SNAT --to-source 10.4.5.6:6343
```

It's easy to debug and test if you use netcat in verbose mode instead of samplificator (`nc -n -v -u -l -p 6343`), it will tell you the source seen.